# Make result of auto complete text view clickable in header (React Native)

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation, google-places-autocomplete

I've a react native App, I've implemented navigation using react-navigation version 4. For Map screen I've a custom [search](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) component in the header. That search shows auto complete results on top of the screen which is visible on the map but when I click on the resulted item, it actually clicks the Map which is in the background.

Has any one ever faced such issue or know the solution, please help.

Comment: try this style={{zIndex:2}}

Comment: already done, not working

Comment: not sure try this. <View style={{position:'absolute', top:10, left:10, right:10, flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}>... place your search element here</View>

Comment: I have the same style. Not working

Comment: remove position,top,left,right, give some flex:1, margin and padding, zindex let see